# Why .obj does not react to directional light? [three.js]

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Anyone knows why the *.obj* doesn't reflect the directional light like the box?

Both are with the same material.

Here's the code in GitHub: https://github.com/triple-verge/triple-verge-website/blob/master/src/js/modules/logo-3d.js#L52

And here's the piece of the code:

```
logo.addLogo = function () {
    loader.load('img/logo.obj', function (obj) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                color: 0xff0000
            }),
            cube; // Test

        _logo.obj = obj;

        obj.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.geometry.applyMatrix(
                    new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(-0.5, 0, 0)
                );

                child.material = material;

                // Test
                cube = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
                    material
                );

                $(_logo.container).on('frame', function () {
                    child.position.set(0, Math.sin(Date.now() / 750) * 0.1, 0);
                    child.rotation.set(
                        Math.PI * 0.5,
                        0,
                        Math.sin(Date.now() / 500) * 0.8
                    );
                    cube.rotation.set(
                        Math.PI * 0.5,
                        0,
                        Math.sin(Date.now() / 500) * 0.8
                    );
                });
            }
        });

        _logo.scene.add(obj);
        _logo.scene.add(cube); // Test
    });
};
```

Thanks!

three.js r.70

Comment: Your obj file does not appear to specify normals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to export vertex normals in your obj file, or call

```
child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

in your `traverse()` method inside the loader callback function.

three.js r.70